# Automated spacing

Tags: spacing

Suppose I would like to customize and automate the spacing around em-dash. Say, I'd like to have hair-space before and after. Is there a package or something which would enable me achieve that? The procedure shall be able to work in all possible scenarios—e.g. if there is no space around it, put hair-space, if there is inter-word  space on one or both sides, strip it and replace it with hair-space, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `ltugboat.cls` contains a clever set of macros for dashes

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\thinskip}{\hskip 0.16667em\relax}
\def\endash{--}
\def\emdash{\endash-}
\def\d@sh#1#2{\unskip#1\thinskip#2\thinskip\ignorespaces}
\def\dash{\d@sh\nobreak\endash}
\def\Dash{\d@sh\nobreak\emdash}
\def\ldash{\d@sh\empty{\hbox{\endash}\nobreak}}
\def\rdash{\d@sh\nobreak\endash}
\def\Ldash{\d@sh\empty{\hbox{\emdash}\nobreak}}
\def\Rdash{\d@sh\nobreak\emdash}
```

Here `\unskip` kills the preceding spaces and `\ignorespaces` kills the following ones, and then the macros set up hair spaces around a dash.

You can either adopt these macros and use `\Dash` instead of `---`, or to write your own macro modeled after these ideas.

If you use these macros, do not forget to enclose them in `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` pair.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Is there a collection of typography-related “clever” macros which may come handy?

Comment: I'd recommend reading TUGboat, http://tug.org/TUGboat/

Comment: As I understand, the above macro defines same spacing around both em-dash and en-dash. How can I differentiate en-dash? For en-dash, I want even smaller spacing?

Comment: \DeclareRobustCommand{\extrathinskip}{\hskip 0.13em\relax}\def\ddash{\unskip\nobreak\extrathinskip\endash\extrathinskip\ignorespaces}